# Why is Active class not shown correctly in Inspect Element when NavLink is written next to another class name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
import React from "react";
import {NavLink} from "react-router-dom";

const MenuItem = ({items}) => {

  const activeClassMenuItem = ({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "active_link" : "");

  return (
    <>
      {items.map((item) => {
        return (
          <li className="menu-item" key={item.id}>
            <NavLink
              to={item.url}
              className={`menu-link ${activeClassMenuItem}`}
            >
              <div data-i18n={item.title}>{item.title}</div>
            </NavLink>
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default MenuItem;
```

Show result in inspect element : ( 'active_link' class is also placed)

```
<li class="menu-item ">
   <a class="menu-link  _ref2 => { let { isActive } = _ref2; return isActive ? "active_link" : "" } active_link" href="/Login">
       Login
   </a>
</li>
```

When I try from NavLink to have the 'active_link' class next to other classes of that element, unfortunately, the output is not placed correctly in Inspect Element.

Answer (score 1):

`activeClassMenuItem` is a function you need to do it like this (I assume item has a property called isActive):

```js
import React from "react";
import {NavLink} from "react-router-dom";

const MenuItem = ({items}) => {

  const activeClassMenuItem = ({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "active_link" : "");

  return (
    <>
      {items.map((item) => {
        return (
          <li className="menu-item" key={item.id}>
            <NavLink
              to={item.url}
              className={`menu-link ${activeClassMenuItem(item)}`}
            >
              <div data-i18n={item.title}>{item.title}</div>
            </NavLink>
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default MenuItem;
```